# Cannot connect to xdebug (running on xampp for mac) via php script

Tags: php, macos, xampp, xdebug

I try to run the following PHP script and nothing happens:

```
$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 9000;
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) or die('Unable to bind');
socket_listen($sock);
$client = socket_accept($sock);
echo "connection established: $client";
socket_close($client);
socket_close($sock);
```

It appears to just hang.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.  I added the following to my php.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_enable =1
xdebug.remote_hander =dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_host =127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
```